# Change html5 video player size for static files served by NGINX

Tags: html, nginx

I want to access some of the files from my home server over HTTPS.

I set up an NGINX server with the following configuration:

```
location /files/ {
    autoindex on;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

and everything seems to be working OK.

The only annoyance I have is that when I access music or video files, the HTML5 player that comes up is usually very small. I can easily change its size using the Chrome "inspect element" menu, by adding an `element.style` property:

```
width: 600px;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get NGINX to set this property automatically when it is serving media files. Maybe there is some sort of default CSS file that I can edit?

Comment: This default css is in you browser, not nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alexey-ten commented, this is a property of the browser, not of Nginx.

I ended up changing the default script using the following tempermonkey script:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    console.log('hello');
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    console.log(elem);
    elem[0].style.width = "100%";
})();
```